# Can we have a dbt query that sources from two different databases (datasets) in the same project?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dbt

I have one dbt project that is deployed on one single GCP project.
Within the GCP project, I have multiple datasets in BigQuery, which I want to run my query on.

So my compiled SQL code should look something like:

```
with 
  first_table as (
    select * from projectA.dataset_X.table_thishasinfo
  )
  second_table as (
    select * from projectA.dataset_Y.table_thishasmoreinfo
 select * 
from first_table ft
left join second_table st
on ft.id = st.id
```

Within dbt, these are of course references to the files in different models where they are created.

The query needs to write to a table `proejctA.dataset_Z.table_thisistheoutput`

I tried looking at `target` within dbt, or defining it in profiles, but I can't figure out how to have three different datasets involved in the project.

How could I write my dbt code to create a query that can run on multiple datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue is resolved by editing the `dbt_project.yml` file.

If you include the following:

```
models: 
  <projectname>:
    <modelname>:
       database: projectA
       schema: dataset_X
    <modelname2>:
       database: projectA
       schema: dataset_Y
    <modelname3>:
       database: projectA
       schema: dataset_Z
```

If you run all the models in the same production environment, let's say with a prefix `dbt`, then in your BQ, you will see the following three datasets:
`dbt_dataset_X`, `dbt_dataset_Y`, `dbt_dataset_Z. And the queries will pick up the correct database to source from.